# RedHawk 2.0 final release

Tags: redhawksdr

I previously installed the RedHawk 2.0 version dated 29 Oct 2015 but I now see on the RedHawk home page that there is a RedHawk 2.0 final release dated from Dec 2015.  I downloaded the tar.gz, which has the same name as the one I installed before but a different sha1 checksum.  So I untar'ed it and tried to update using yum but it found that no rpm's had new version numbers and so it said nothing to be done (yet diff says nearly every file has changed).  How do I update to this newer release?  If this is newer why didn't the version number go to 2.0.1 or at least the version numbers of the rpm's change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what the deal is, but easiest thing to do would be remove all current redhawk stuff and replace with new:

```
sudo yum remove redhawk*
cd <redhawk-2.0.0...>
sudo yum install *rpm
```